How do I download and install Android Studio JellyFish?
Hi I've downloaded the latest Android Studio Koala, but I find it a bit buggy.  No matter what I try it takes 1 hour (not joking) to build and deploy to emulator and sometimes never completes.  It says it has internal errors, so it temporarily closes syntax highlighting, and many more problems.  I want to go back to JellyFish because everything worked in that one, but I can't find the download page.  Can somebody show me how to download a previous Android Studio?

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

just download toolbox and you are see all the android studio version.

https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/2023.3.1.20/android-studio-2023.3.1.20-windows.exe

To download a previous version of Android Studio, such as JellyFish, follow these steps:
Visit the Android Studio Archive page.
Scroll down to find the version you want to download.
Click on the desired version (e.g., Android Studio 2022.1.1 for JellyFish) to expand the section.
Download the appropriate installer for your operating system.
Uninstall the current version of Android Studio before installing the older version to avoid conflicts.
Install the downloaded version and configure it as needed.
This should resolve the issues you're experiencing with the latest Android Studio Koala.

You can download the Jetbrains Toolbox App which can streamline managing different versions of Android Studio
And the best part is, you can even have multiple Android Studio versions, just in case you want to check the performance, just like your case
Alternatively you can go the Android Studio archives  and pick the version that you want if you want to rollback

You can download any old android versions at https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.
